# Accessing strings based on score

Tags: unity, c#

I have strings named like this:

```
list_1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
list_2 = {"v", "t", "d"};
list_3 = {"e", "a", "b"};
..
list_100 = {"g", "q", "z"};
```

and I have a variable:

```
int counter;
```

and I have `string[] myList;` which I define as below:

```
if (counter==1){
   myList = list_1;
} 
else if (counter==2){
   myList = list_2;
} 
else if (counter==3){
   myList = list_3;
} 
...

else {
    myList = list_100;
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this code, so that `if score == i`, then I can assign `myList = list_i`?

ty so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you want an array of arrays, also called a [jagged array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) (since each row could have its own length):

```
string[][] allLists = new string[][]{
   new string[]{"a", "b", "c"},
   new string[]{"d", "e", "f"},
   ...
};

string[] myList = allLists[counter - 1];
```

Or you could do it with a [two-dimensional array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays),

```
string[,] table = new string[,]{
  {"a", "b", "c"},
  {"d", "e", "f"},
  ...
}
```

And then replace any access of `myList[i]` with `table[counter - 1, i]` to index both your desired row and column.

This is very beginner C#, so you might want to work through some more introductory tutorials for the language to get familiar with these fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [List<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) for that (not sure about the exact syntax in c#):

```
List<string[]> lists = new List<string[]>();
lists.Add( new string[]{"a", "b", "c"});
lists.Add( new string[]{"v", "t", "d"} );
lists.Add( new string[]{"e", "a", "b"} );
..
lists.Add( new string[]{"g", "q", "z"} );
```

then

```
string[] myList;
if ( counter >= 1 && counter <= lists.Count )
    myList = lists[counter - 1];
else 
    myList = lists[lists.Count - 1]
```

---

You could also achieve this with a [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) (again, not sure about the exact syntax in c#):

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> scoresTexts = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();

scoresTexts.Add( 1, new string[]{"a", "b", "c"});
scoresTexts.Add( 2, new string[]{"v", "t", "d"} );
scoresTexts.Add( 3, new string[]{"e", "a", "b"} );
..
scoresTexts.Add( 100, new string[]{"g", "q", "z"} );
```

then:

```
string[] myList;
if (!scoresTexts.TryGetValue(score, out myList))
    myList = scoresTexts[100];
```

---

In any case, I think [DMGregory's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/174780/40264) suggests approaches that are more efficient than those proposed here.